# How to change UITableViewCell content view size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have UITableViewCell its height is set to 60. UITableViewCell content view height is set to 59.5 automatically and it is not possible to edit it in the size inspector. This is the reason all the text in those cells becomes blurry.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: cell's contentview will take cell's height automatically. So if u want increase or deacrease height of cell use heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method it will help you

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      return height you want for cell ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use this method

Answer (score 1):

**Return Height from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     return x; //CGFloat

}
```

May be blur you seeing is because of Scale of simulator(if you are using simulator).

So, for simulator check in `Window --> Scale`, is it 100% or not.